# iphone/ipad - two different targets, conflicts in view controllers

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, targets

So I have created a new iPad target in Xcode for a project that originally was iPhone only. As Apple recommends, I have also created iPad-specific view controllers, and copied and pasted much of the iphone view controller code into the ipad versions. The problem is that I have a lot of conflicts with #defines and enums.

If I have this:

```
#define birdSize 175
```

I'd rather not have to re-define it in the iPad view controller as:

```
#define birdSize_iPad 400
```

and then search and replace all the instances in the implementation. I'd like to just change the defined value, but that would affect the iPhone version. Two questions:

1. Why are there conflicts when these view controllers are included in different targets?
2. What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

1.) It seems like you import the header file with your "#define birdSize" also in your iPad View Controller. Maybe indirectly? If you could show us your imports, it would be easier to say...

2.) I don't know about the "best way", but here is how I solved this:
Target Options for iPad -> Build Settings -> GCC CFLAGS

```
-DIPAD
```

then you can easily have one definition of birdSize somewhere, that would look like:

```
#ifdef IPAD
  #define birdSize 400
#else
  #define birdSize 175
#endif
```

Maybe not the most elegant way, but it works fine for me.